# Nginx location directive returning 405 Method Not allowed error

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I am trying to add the Rate limiting using Nginx. I have to add this to my `domain.com/api/index.php` file.

When I am adding the following location block then the Nginx is returning 405 (method not allowed) error on the URL when it passes the user request and the rest of the requests are returning 503 error.

I am trying to fix this 405 error from my file. I believe that I am doing something wrong and I am not able to find it. I am new with Nginx and this is the first time I am attempting this. The following are my settings.

```
location = /domain.com/api/index.php {
    root /var/www/;
    limit_req zone=mylimit burst=2 nodelay;            
}
```

Upon testing this URL return 405 error and request limit return 503 after every 2 connections. Can anyone please tell me what's wrong here and how to fix it?

I am still not able to figure out the issue and its fix. Can anyone please help?

Comment: What's the request you are doing?

Comment: I ran an ajax on this link and on 200ms interval. for testing